# Is using an iterator to clone a BST faster than recursion?

Tags: java, clone, binary-tree, deep-copy

I had a question about a Binary Sorted Tree design principle.

I need to create a deep copy of a Binary Expression Tree, and I am accomplishing this by going through all the nodes in the tree and creating a new, identical one.

I already have a treeIterator set up for other uses and was wondering if an iterator would be faster, slower, or about the same speed/memory usage as doing it recursively.

Thanks!

Comment: you have prev/next links as well?

Comment: in that case the copy would be better off w/ recursion (or stack) since adding a new node in the new tree would be O(1) instead of O(logN) [provided you do not need to re-balance it]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think recursion would be faster.

I don't know your iterator's exact implementation, but I assume that it goes to each node? If your BST is based on a root node structure, then going to each node (as in a iterator) would be slower than recursion.

Here's how I would implement it:

Recursively,
Create a new root node (identical to the original root node).
Add copies of the original root's left and right nodes. (If they exist)

Comment: That's only true if the iterator in question is not smart enough to do an in-order walk...

Comment: I don't know how he implemented it... so that's why I suggest recursion.

Comment: Ah, now we have information-- no parent links, so recursion is probably the only way it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify how you would implement the iterator. The iterator is just an interface, not a specific implementation.

Searching in a BST takes *O(log n)* time, which implies that at any point in time, finding the next node should take O(log n) time.

Explanation:
The next node is always either the smallest element in the right subtree or the parent of the current node. In any case, it will not take more than *log n* time.

Unless your iterator implementation takes less than *O(log n)* time, recursion will be faster.

Edit : I need to point out that the O-notation here is for average case, not for the worst case. However, assuming that you have a fairly balanced tree, *log n* should still apply.

Comment: for the -1 : please explain what was wrong about my answer and why

Answer (score 0):

There's two parts: (1) walking the tree and (2) creating a new tree copy. I assume by iteration you mean a loop that maintains the position in the tree manually. This is likely faster/less memory than recursion. However, when building a new tree it's probably better to use recursion and build the tree as you walk it. If you iterate and insert the node into a new tree that's going to take O(n lg n). Recursion, on the other hand, will take just O(n), though you may blow out your stack on very deep trees.